# Several unsuccessful login attempts from several stations

Tags: logging, mapping, windows-server, event-viewer, localserver

I have a problem. I apologize for the English. The problem lies in the mapping of the disk. This disk has one program and a local database in it, when the user has the disk mapped I see several failed login attempts in the event viewer and when I log into the application these failed attempts stop, but as soon as I log out of the application the logs of failed login attempts jump again.

Any advice on what to check or if this is a problem of the app or the mapping? I've tried just about every way to map the drive, but the problem persists.

Overall everything is working, just these failed login attempts are jumping in. Even if the user sets all the parameters (username and password for mapping and for the program it self), it keeps throwing these failed attempts.

Around 100 users use the app

The server is WINDOWS.
It uses NTLM protocol for autentication

I hope something helps

I tried remapping the disks and investigating the problem, but I can't find anything that helps.

here is some example of the unsuccessful log

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       User
    Account Domain:     INT

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   PC-XXXX
    Source Network Address: 10.0.XXX.XXX
    Source Port:        64477

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.